# Cost of CAL for SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Does anyone know what the approximate cost of CAL's for accessing a SharePoint Foundation 2010 server is ?

We're still a Windows 2003 site, but were interested in going to SPF 2010, and we're going to be a copy of Windows 2008 R2 for a box to host SPF, but someone reckons we'll need to update everyone CAL's who access SPF, from 2003 to 2008 ?

Is this true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CALs for SPF are included as part of your Windows Server CALS I believe. Upgrade to server 2008, and all your SPF CALs are updated too.

Only separate CALs come into play when you use SharePoint Server